# Time picker plugin is stopping my JQuery script

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to fix my jQuery code which was working fine before installing time picker plugin, now the values of the input field are changing by time picker so its not listing to the event:

HTML:

```
<input 
    name="pickup" 
    type="text" 
    class="m-wrap input-smaller transedit clockface_2" 
    value="" 
    readonly />

<button class="btn clockface_2_toggle" type="button" ></button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('.transedit').on('change keyup', function() 
{
    alert('time changeded');
});

 $('.clockface_2').clockface({
        format: 'HH:mm',
        trigger: 'manual'
    });

    $('.clockface_2_toggle').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropagation();
        $(this).closest('tr').find($('.clockface_2')).clockface('toggle');
    });
```

Comment: It works just fine (once you fix the `:` typo): http://jsfiddle.net/b2xjoj3c/ The only problem is that keyboard changing of the value is not supported so `keyup` is pretty pointless.

Comment: it has a button beside it that triggers the time picker as a light box it changes the values but the script not lestning to it, so its not alerting

Comment: Now it has a `button` and a `lightbox`! Please post your complete HTML. Don't make us guess :)

Comment: yes you are right TrueBlueAussie sorry about that, here i inserted the button which triggers the time picker plugin

Comment: You are using Datepicker from jQuery ui right? http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

Comment: i'm using Clockface http://vitalets.github.io/clockface/

Comment: The plugin is not doing its job properly. It uses `val()` to set the input, but does not also trigger a `change()` event. Answer below with suggested fixes to the plugin.

Comment: P.S. IMHO that is one of the ugliest time pickers I have ever seen (styling issues more than functionality). The concept is good though.

Comment: :) well yes it looks ugly, just please give me something to replace my listener so instead of on change or keyup need something else like propertychange or so

Comment: $('.transedit').on('pick.clockface', function()  this one works and it alert but not in my case, please don't ask me why its complicated

Comment: @Nasser: If my suggestion to use `$('.transedit').on('pick.clockface', function()` works, but not in "your" code, then the problem is possibly in your other code not shown. If you can provide your complete page and code this will be easier. Otherwise please explain the remaining problem *carefully* :)

Comment: ok in fact i'm using this code $('.transedit').on('change keyup', function() for one more field has the same class, after using your code $('.transedit').on('pick.clockface', function() it wroks for the time field but of-course it ignored the other field, so i need to keep the class selector but use another event

Comment: hey @TrueBlueAussie ;; works now its listen to my even after i change the code at them plugin by adding change(); where  you show me thank you very much :) just saved my life

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66495/discussion-between-nasser-and-trueblueaussie).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had a look at their plugin source code here: https://github.com/vitalets/clockface/blob/master/js/clockface.js.

The reason your events do not work is because they set the input value with `val()` but do not trigger a `change` event. `val()` by itself *does not* trigger a change event.

The code is marked with `<<<< HERE` below.

```
    /*
    Click cell handler.
    Stores hour/minute and highlights.
    On second click deselect value
    */
    click: function(e) {
      var $target = $(e.target),
          value = $target.hasClass('active') ? null : $target.text();
      if($target.hasClass('inner')) {
        this.setHour(value);
      } else {
        this.setMinute(value);
      }

      //update value in input
      if(!this.isInline) {
        this.$element.val(this.getTime());          // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
      }          

      //trigger pick event
      this.$element.triggerHandler('pick.clockface', this.getTime(true));  
    },

    /*
    Click handler on ampm link
    */
    clickAmPm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //toggle am/pm
      this.setAmPm(this.ampm === 'am' ? 'pm' : 'am');

      //update value in input
      if(!this.isInline && !this.is24) {
        this.$element.val(this.getTime());          // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< HERE
      }    

      //trigger pick event
      this.$element.triggerHandler('pick.clockface', this.getTime(true));                  
    },
```

The solution is to fix the plugin so that it triggers a *change* event after setting the input value:

```
    /*
    Click cell handler.
    Stores hour/minute and highlights.
    On second click deselect value
    */
    click: function(e) {
      var $target = $(e.target),
          value = $target.hasClass('active') ? null : $target.text();
      if($target.hasClass('inner')) {
        this.setHour(value);
      } else {
        this.setMinute(value);
      }

      //update value in input
      if(!this.isInline) {
        this.$element.val(this.getTime()).change();      // <<<<<< HERE
      }          

      //trigger pick event
      this.$element.triggerHandler('pick.clockface', this.getTime(true));  
    },

    /*
    Click handler on ampm link
    */
    clickAmPm: function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      //toggle am/pm
      this.setAmPm(this.ampm === 'am' ? 'pm' : 'am');

      //update value in input
      if(!this.isInline && !this.is24) {
        this.$element.val(this.getTime()).change();      // <<<<<< HERE;
      }    

      //trigger pick event
      this.$element.triggerHandler('pick.clockface', this.getTime(true));                  
    },
```

I think the simpler alternative may be to listen for their custom `pick.clockface` event in your code instead, but you may want to play with this option as I have never used that plugin:

e.g.

```
$('.transedit').on('pick.clockface', function() 
{
    alert('time changeded');
});
```

Comment: @Nasser: Glad we got there :)

Answer (score 0):

Change `:` to `;` at the end of `alert` function:

```
$('.transedit').on('change keyup', function() {

                alert('time changeded');
            });
```

Comment: thanks but still not working the proplem is its not listening to keyup or change